# Browser fails to cache page assets for Rails 4 Site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, caching, browser-cache

When accessing our Rails 4 site, we used the Chrome developer tools to view our Network performance and to monitor the page load speeds of various assets. This showed that very few assets were/are being cached.

Files such as the application-*.js and appliation-*.css files, which we're positive have not changed between page loads, are also not being cached.

Within our config/environments/production.rb file we have configured the following:

```
    # Code is not reloaded between requests.
    config.cache_classes = true

    # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
    # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
    # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
    # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
    config.eager_load = true

    # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
    config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
    config.serve_static_files = false

    # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
    config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
    config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

    # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
    config.assets.compile = false

    # Generate digests for assets URLs.
    config.assets.digest = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

    # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
    config.log_level = :info

    # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
    # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
    config.i18n.fallbacks = true

    # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
    config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

    # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
    config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
```

Any thoughts on why this may be happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the Browser settings that I was testing with. Quit and relaunched the browser and the static elements once again were cached as expected.